# how to populate the scope data in modal page and how to handle the click events in modal box in angular js

Tags: angularjs

**Iam able to open the modal when i click on get label**

**how to pass the scope variable 'item' from myCtrl to modal**

**code for    myModal.html**

```
//below is the modal to show when we click on button in main page and display the item value in the modal-body
//when we click on the save changes how to invoke the method
<div class="modal " tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding" ng-bind-html="title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{item}}

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modalClose()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**//code main html page**

```
<div ng-app="test">
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <label ng-click="openModal()">GET</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

****//code in js****

```
 var app = angular.module('test', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl',[ui.bootstrap], function($scope,$modal) {
        $scope.item= "welcome....";
        $scope.openModal= function(){
           var myModal = $modal({ title: 'My Title', template: 'modalEx.html', show: true });
                myModal.$promise.then(myModal.show);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Select the answer as correct, if was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `resolve` and `controller` field in modal config. For example:

```
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  },
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
```

and in your modal controller:

```
  controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items)
```

You have items on `items` varible.